# How to increase width of \titlerule in \titleformat?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, rules

I want to change the width of the `\titlerule` under every section, the following is my code, I am using `\titling` and `\titlesec` packages in order to achieve that. The documentation said I can do  `{\titlerule*[width]}`
but it pushes the sections to end of the line. The following works fine but the line is too thin. How can I change the thickness of the line here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\huge\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}[\titlerule]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\titlerule` command takes an optional width argument. Because you're using it inside an argument delimited with  `[ ]` then you need to wrap the command in `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\huge\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}[{\titlerule[4pt]}]
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]